# Simple Example with Object containing Object--understanding Objects and OOP

Tags: c#, oop, object

Pls I really don't know hot to combine my two objects.

Here I already managed to read all the Customer Data into an object-array.

```
public void GettingCustomers()
{
    Customer customer = new Customer(); //correct ???
    // -----READINGLOOP from Source-------
    Name = "Name1";
    Id = 1;
    // -----READINGLOOP from Source-------
}
```

Here I already managed to read all the data from a SPECIFIC customer:

```
public void GettingObjectsFromDB()
{
    // -----READING all Objects belonging to CUSTOMER Name1!!
    ObjectName = "Ball";
    ObjectNumber = 555;
    //------LOOP
}
```

But now I am stuck for many hours on how to combine these two,...so that in the end I can output all objects from a Customer object.

```
using System;

namespace Classes
{

class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    puclic object Objects /////   ----??

    public void GettingCustomers()
    {
     // getting Customer List
    }
}

class Objects
{
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
    public int ObjectNumber { get; set; }

    public void GettingObjectsFromDB()
    {
      // getting all Objects from a specific CUSTOMER.
      // used a tempstring="Name1" until now.
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Print out Objects belonging to "Name1"     
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Pretty sure SO is not a _wiki site_

Comment: Well how to make it to work...I can handle objects-arrays and Properties...set them..print out etc.....but this is a object inside and object...and I am reading and reading, but don't know what to do. It should be pretty easy for someone with experience to make that one example work,...I mean no Loops nothing, just the hardcoded examplestrings. From there it would be easier.  I am lost what to do next :(

Comment: It's still very much unclear *what* you're trying to make work here. The usual object-based approach would be simply to have a collection of `Objects` in `Customer`, and then you've got your pretty arrays back. Of course, making that work well with the relational database you're most likely using is anything but trivial :) Don't expect to get any useful answers, though - it's very likely this question is going to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: wow sorry for that, but sometimes its hard to formulate thee question if you don't know what you are looking for exactly, but collection of Objects in Customer is exactly what i need. I am a bit frustrated since I managed that DB stuck pretty good, but now I hit a wall in understanding. I will try to edit the code, so it goes more to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 1 to many relationship between customers and 'objects'. 1 Customer having many objects.

Your database tables should look like the following:

Customer (CustomerId {pk}, Name, Surname, Address, etc.)
Object (ObjectId {pk}, CustomerId {fk}, Name, etc.)

Personally I like to use EntityFramework to generate everything, but whether you use EF or do it yourself, you would end up with the following:

```
class Customer
{
   public int CustomerId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   ...
   public IEnumerable<Object> Objects {get; set;}
}

class Object
{
   public int ObjectId {get; set;}
   public int CustomerId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

I suggest you use Entity Framework with a database first approach. If you don't do that, then when you fetch a customer from the db you also fetch all the objects by using the customerid in that table.

Comment: I think I understand everything a bit better now.  I am going to use built-in arrays only, and forget this generic stuff for now,...performance wise it will be better anyway. My Data is collected from DB and a big Data chunk which needs to be split,....anyway this link help me alot. http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Choosing_the_right_collection_type#ArrayLists    public IEnumerable<Object> Objects {get; set;}<<--- btw thx....that was one missing element